# Remote access local mysql server

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using Laravel and Hostinger as a web hosting, how will i get or send data to my local database on ubuntu ? Can you suggest any solution on how will i do this ? thank you!

Comment: A blockchain is isolated from the outside world. To interact with it from a contract you need an oracle that interact with the world and send the request to the contract.